# Ansible django_manage throws UnicodeDecodeError on ubuntu server 18.04 but running the command manually works fine

Tags: python, django, ansible

I have a project (`python 3.6`, `django v2.1`) that I deploy using `Ansible v2.4.6` to my VM `ubuntu server 18.04` (on the old `ubuntu server 16.04` there is no problem, everything works fine).

I have a custom `Django` management command called `ensure_initial_data`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        perm_list = [
            {
                'content_type': ContentType.objects.get(
                    app_label='app_accounting', model='account'),
                'codename': 'account_list',
                'name': 'ver lista de cuentas',
            },
            {
                'content_type': ContentType.objects.get(
                    app_label='app_accounting', model='summary'),
                'codename': 'summary_list',
                'name': 'ver lista de resúmenes',
            },
        ]

        self.stdout.write('Creating missing permissions ...')
        for i, kwargs in enumerate(perm_list):
            p, _ = Permission.objects.get_or_create(**kwargs)

            self.stdout.write('   {:03d} {:15s} {:40s} {}'.format(
                i + 1,
                p.content_type.app_label,
                p.codename,
                p.name))
```

Which I try to call it in `Ansible` like this:

```
- name: run django "ensure_initial_data"
  django_manage:
    command: 'ensure_initial_data'
    app_path: '{{ django_app_base_dir }}'
    virtualenv: '{{ django_app_base_dir }}/.venv'
  notify: restart gunicorn app in supervisor
```

it throws the following error (because of the letter with accent in the second `Permission`, in the word `resúmenes`):

```
TASK [webserver : run django "ensure_initial_data"] ******************************************************************************************************
fatal: [ubuntu1]: FAILED! => {
  "changed": false,
  "cmd": "./manage.py ensure_initial_data",
  "failed": true,
  "msg": "
    stdout:
      Creating missing permissions ...
        001     app_accounting    account_list    ver lista de cuentas contables
    stderr:
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File \"./manage.py\", line 29, in <module>
          execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
        File \"/var/webapps/tb_system_01/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py\", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
          utility.execute()
        File \"/var/webapps/tb_system_01/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py\", line 375, in execute
          self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
        File \"/var/webapps/tb_system_01/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py\", line 316, in run_from_argv
          self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
        File \"/var/webapps/tb_system_01/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py\", line 353, in execute
          output = self.handle(*args, **options)
        File \"/var/webapps/tb_system_01/base/management/commands/ensure_initial_data.py\", line 23, in handle
          p.name))
        File \"/var/webapps/tb_system_01/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py\", line 145, in write
          self._out.write(style_func(msg))
      UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\\xfa' in position 91: ordinal not in range(128)
    ",
  "path": "/var/webapps/tb_system_01/.venv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games",
  "state": "absent",
  "syspath": ["/tmp/ansible_u0w79rmt", "/tmp/ansible_u0w79rmt/ansible_modlib.zip", "/tmp/ansible_u0w79rmt/ansible_modlib.zip", "/usr/lib/python36.zip", "/usr/lib/python3.6", "/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload", "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages", "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages"]}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************************
ubuntu1                    : ok=71   changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

But the command completes successfully when I run it manually (connecting via SSH to VM and running `./manage.py ensure_initial_data`):

```
Creating missing permissions ...
  001     app_accounting    account_list    ver lista de cuentas contables
  002     app_accounting    summary_list    ver lista de resúmenes
```

So this does not seem to be a problem with `Django` nor `Postgres` (because  it runs fine when launched manually), and it also works fine if I use the previous LTS version `ubuntu server 16.04`; it seems that `Ansible` gets somehow confused on the new `ubuntu server 18.04`.

There is an github [issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/22834) with my exact problem, but it was closed without solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: The only difference I could think of was that `ubuntu server 18.04` uses `Python 3.6` as its default while `16.04` uses `Python 2.7`; maybe that is somehow related, but I don't know where I would start to research that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a smilar problem with Flask and Docker. The problem was `locale` env variables was not arranged. The following commands is handling it.

```
locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US:en
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: Where/when should this be run? On the VM through ansible before the `django_manage` part?

Comment: I guess it s better to run before django.

Comment: I got it working just by adding `environment: LC_ALL: 'en_US.UTF-8'` to the task that runs `django_manage` (which is depicted in my question); the other 2 env variables were not needed for my case.